# Material UI IconButton onClick to increment or decrement values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, button, material-ui

I'm trying to implement the `onClick()` of a **Material UI IconButton**, that will **decrement** or **increment** the *Calories* value of each element in the table, like this. My code is based on the [Table React component page code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/y086e)

[image]

In this case, if I click in the *[ - ]* button, it will **decrement** the value to 2, and if I click in the [ + ] button, it will **increment** the value to 4.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

//Icons
import AddCircleOutlineRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircleOutlineRounded';
import RemoveCircleOutlineRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/RemoveCircleOutlineRounded';

/*------------------------- IMPORTS ---------------------------*/

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650,
  },
});

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

export default function DenseTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>

/* ----------------- IconButton HERE ---------------- */

              <TableCell align="right">
              <IconButton onClick={ --row.calories }>
              <RemoveCircleOutlineRoundedIcon />
              </IconButton> 
              {row.calories} 
              <IconButton onClick={ ++row.calories }>
              <AddCircleOutlineRoundedIcon />
              </IconButton>
              </TableCell>

/* ----------------- IconButton END ---------------- */

              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>

              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>

              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>

            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

In the 2 `IconButtons`, I'm trying to decrement or increment `Calories` value using `onClick()`, but the way I'm doing this isn't working. What should I do? I think I need to use the component `state` and therefore, the `setState()`function, but I've no idea how to assign this and get that value.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You must use `setState` in `onClick`. I'll tell you how to do it after I point out the mistakes you made.

There are few mistakes you're doing here,

**Mistake 1:** Not maintaining `row` in a React State. All the dynamic data must be stored as a React State.

**Mistake 2:** `onClick` isn't a function but a number. `--row.Calorie` isn't a function, it's an expression which outputs number.

**Mistake 3:** Mutating the data directly. This is strictly prohibited in React and Functional Programming. You should not type expressions like `--row.Calorie`. They directly mutate the data and React cannot track the changes.

Make these adjustments and you're good to go.

```
// Straight away create a row state like this.
const [rows, setRows] = useState([
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
])

// inside map function
rows.map((row, index) => (
  // ...
  <IconButton
    // pass a function instead of expression
    onClick={() => {
      // NOTE: I'm using only index and prev in this block
      // and not using row, or directly mutating them
      setRows(prev => [
        ...prev.slice(0, index),
        { ...prev[index], calories: prev[index].calories - 1 }, 
        ...prev.slice(index + 1)
      ])
      // Also NOTE: I'm creating a new state
      // from the previous state - `prev` without
      // mutating the `prev`
    }}
  >
    <RemoveCircleOutlineRoundedIcon />
  </IconButton>
  // ...

))
```

Answer (score 0):

The next code make the work.

You must to think in the next cycle:
when increment or decrement must to update the store value,
then in the `row.map` show the *store* value.

It is the basic way to understand how react work.

In this case you use **Hooks** to set the *state* of your *store*,

I recommend to you learn **Redux**.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

//Icons
import AddCircleOutlineRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircleOutlineRounded';
import RemoveCircleOutlineRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/RemoveCircleOutlineRounded';

/*------------------------- IMPORTS ---------------------------*/

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650,
  },
});

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

export default function DenseTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();


  const [calories, setCalories] = React.useState(rows);// set initial state is used only once

  console.log(calories);


  const onDecrement = key => () => {     
        setCalories( calories.map( (item, index) => item.name === key ? 
          {...item, calories: item.calories -1} : item));          
  };

  const onIncrement = key => () => {     
        setCalories( calories.map( (item, index) => item.name === key ? 
          {...item, calories: item.calories +1} : item));          
  };


  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {calories.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>



              <TableCell align="right">
              <IconButton onClick={ onDecrement(row.name) }>
              <RemoveCircleOutlineRoundedIcon />
              </IconButton> 
              {row.calories} 
              <IconButton onClick={ onIncrement(row.name)  }>
              <AddCircleOutlineRoundedIcon />
              </IconButton>
              </TableCell>



              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>

              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>

              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>

            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React renders a component as a function of state and props, this makes the rendering deterministic (i.e for a given input the output will always be the same), this criteria allows react to know when to render a page.
So whenever the state or props change the component is rendered again to reflect the change.

In your case [onClick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) expects a function - an event handler. When user clicks your element, how should the element handle it? This needs to be defined by the user as a function.

```
          <IconButton
            onClick={() => {
                --row.calories;
                alert("Decremented to " + row.calories);
              }}
            >
              <RemoveCircleOutlineRoundedIcon />
            </IconButton>
            {row.calories}
            <IconButton
              onClick={() => {
                ++row.calories;
                alert("Incremented to " + row.calories);
              }}
            >
```

so we added a function and we can see that the value is reflected in the alert accurately. But the page doesn't seem to reflect the current value of calorie. This is because we never informed react that something was changed by user.

This could be done through state, we can choose to use state when we know some data can be altered by user and it needs to be rendered.
State belongs to a component. State can be simple object with a single field or a complex one with multiple fields and objects.

```
let [foodData, setFoodData] = useState(rows);
/* existing code */
<TableBody>
      {foodData.map((row, index) => (
/* existing code */
<IconButton
  onClick={() => {
  setFoodData(prev => [
  ...prev.slice(0, index),
  { ...prev[index], calories: prev[index].calories - 1 },
  ...prev.slice(index + 1)
  ]);
  }}
 >
/* do the same to increment */
```

The '...' is ES6 spread operator and to identify the current row which we want to modify we are using 'index' as a parameter for map function.

Now to modify the object we can create a new array that contains:

- All of the elements from 0 to index
- The object we want to modify
- All of the elements from index + 1 to the end of the array

Array’s slice method can achieve this as it does not modify the original array.

This new array will be set as the current state and react will re-render.

https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/ - the first chapter of the book explains this in detail and introduces to state. **useState** is a hook which could be referred from here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html